# Can I simply move the data in a std::vector to a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++

I would like to send a collection of data via [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/).  The method to do so requires me to provide a pointer to a buffer of unsigned char, along with the length of the buffer.

I plan on collecting the data in a `std::vector` over a period of time and then convert that to the required buffer pointer and length, send it over MQTT, and then collect more data.

Here is what I have so far.  I basically create a `std::unique_ptr` to a block of memory large enough to hold the data, then use std:memcpy to copy the data in.  I *think* this works (my c++ is rusty) , but the use of memcpy makes me think there should be a better way (like somehow just moving the pointer).  Is there a way to simply move the vector data pointer in a `std::unique_ptr`?

BTW, I am not sure I *need* to return a smart pointer.  I *think* I could just return the `payload.data()` pointer, but I want to handle the case were payload object may go out of scope. Also, I still need to implement byte-swapping to handle Endian differences.

```
using byte = unsigned char;

template <typename T> class NumericPayload {

public:    
  size_t getSize() { return sizeof(T) * payload.size(); }
  void addItem(T item) { payload.push_back(item); }
  std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> getBytes() { 
      size_t dataSize = getSize();
      std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> bytes = std::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(dataSize);
      //std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> bytes = std::move(payload);
      std::memcpy(bytes.get(),payload.data(),dataSize);
      std::cout << &bytes << std::endl;
      return bytes;
  }

private:
  std::vector<T> payload;
};



int main() {
    NumericPayload<int> payload;
    payload.addItem(1);
    payload.addItem(2);
    std::cout << payload.getSize() << std::endl;
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> payloadInBytes = payload.getBytes();
    std::cout << &payloadInBytes << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int) payloadInBytes[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` both are smart pointers that do memory management for you.  Since you have a good reason to use the vector (`push_back`), just choose that as your memory-management as well.  Just return `std::move(payload)`.  Yes, the calling code in `main()` will get a `vector<int>` instead of a `unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>`, but you can safely cast the vector's data pointer to `char*` (special allowance in the strict aliasing rule).

Comment: I wouldn't use a `std::unique_ptr`. If you want a copy of the data you may as well store it in another `std::vector` which records the length.

Comment: *"I want to handle the case were payload object may go out of scope"* - I don't see how moving the data from a vector to a unique_ptr helps. Whatever library you're using should either dictate that it uses the buffer contents immediately or has a mechanism for informing you when its done.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I meant I really did not want to return the raw pointer from the vector,  just in case I ended up doing something unforeseen and let that let the original object go out of scope.

Comment: @BenVoigt should probably be encouraged to post that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Ben and Galik,  since I mentioned,  at some point I need to swap the bytes to network Endian,  I think will have to copy the data at some point anyway.  I like the idea of coping it into another vector

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't think you should return ```std::move(payload)```. If you leave out the ```std::move```, guaranteed copy elision will kick in - and otherwise you'll prevent it (which shouldn't even compile).